# Python - How to use random without repeating the previous value

Tags: python

Could You advice how to update code without repeating the previous value.

```
import random
import time

while True :
    a=(random.randint(1,5))
    #print("Number = "+str(a))
    time.sleep(0.8)
    if a == 1:
        print("1")
    if a == 2:
        print("2")
    if a == 3:
        print("3")
    if a == 4:
        print("4")
    if a == 5:
        print("5")
```

[image: example]

Comment: Hey djmcg, What exactly you want to do ? Do you want to get random combination for numbers 1 to 5 ?

Comment: Yes.Random combination for numbers 1 to 5 not repated

Comment: btw. Your ifs are redundant. You can use print(a)

Comment: You need something like a set of numbers to choose from which does not include the last selected item.